# Sort a XML by values inside the tags

Tags: xml, sorting

I have searched a lot of questions about sort XML, but I did not find something that I need.

I have this XML file below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package>
    <types>
        <members>C</members>
        <members>A</members>
        <members>B</members>
        <name>Released</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>B</members>
        <members>A</members>
        <name>Beta</name>
    </types>
<version>45.0</version>
```

Then I want to sort like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package>
    <types>
        <members>A</members>
        <members>B</members>
        <name>Beta</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>A</members>
        <members>B</members>
         <members>C</members>
        <name>Released</name>
    </types>
<version>45.0</version>
</Package>
```

I tried with XLS but I have failed, someone could help me?

Comment: It's always useful to show your unsuccessful attempt. That gives us clues about what you already know and what we need to tell you. It's a waste of time for us to produce a working example from scratch if you were almost there already.

Comment: @MichaelKayI tried to use something like this                                                 
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <package>

      <xsl:for-each select="Package/types">
      <xsl:sort select="members"/>
     
        <members>
        <xsl:value-of select="members"/>
        </members>
    
      </xsl:for-each>

  </package>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: There is more than one "members" child of a "types" element, so both the xsl:sort and the xsl:value-of look wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am late to this conversation, but if you still need help sorting package.xml file. Please try the below from vs code extension

1. Install SF Package.xml Formatter
2. Bring up the command pallet (Ctrl+Shift+P or Cmd+Shift+P on Mac) and run the below command

   > Sort - Salesforce Package.xml Alphabetically Ascending

vs code extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Arif.sf-package-xml-formatter

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: Only works for Salesforce XMLs, not all standard XMLs. It will remove whatever it cannot parse.

Comment: @arminrosu, yes, this vs code extension was specifically made to parse only salesforce package.xml tags and so it will not understand and will not parse any other xml tags.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be sorting at two levels. You're sorting the `<members>` children of a `<types>` within the `<types>` (I find it very confusing to use plural nouns for the tags here, BTW), and you're also sorting the `<types>` elements within a `<Package>` -- but I haven't worked out what your sort criteria here are, with a sample of only two it's a bit hard to detect a pattern.

Sorting the `<members>` elements is easy:

```
<xsl:template match="types">
  <xsl:for-each select="members">
    <xsl:sort select="."/>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
</xsl:template>
```

If your aim is to sort the types based on their members, considering the members in alphabetical order, then I would go for a two-pass solution: first sort the members, then sort the types. But before making the effort to suggest code for that, I would want a clearer description of the requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your help time. My requirement is to file be easier to human read. The file is build to use with Salesforce more detail: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/manifest_samples.htm